# Test whether last letter of a string is upper case or not

Tags: expl3, xparse

I would like to define a command that will behave according to the nature of the last character fed it.  But I'm having difficulty just getting the components of my command to work.

I thought I could grab the last letter of the *string* that I'm passing the command and use `expl` magic to make it upper case.  Then I would test whether the last letter and its upper case version are the same.  But I can't even get that far.

In this MWE, I've defined two commands.  The first command is just supposed to grab the first *token* and change it to upper case.  It fails to do this.  the second is supposed to reverse the string and return only the first token.  That too is failing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_ae_lasttoken_tl
\tl_new:N \l_ae_upper_lasttoken_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\aeupcasefirstelement}{ m }
    {
        \tl_set:Nn  \l_ae_lasttoken_tl        { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
        \tl_set:Nn  \l_ae_upper_lasttoken_tl  { \tl_to_uppercase:n {  \l_ae_lasttoken_tl } }
        %% show results of these actions
        \textbf{ \l_ae_lasttoken_tl {~   vs.  ~} \l_ae_upper_lasttoken_tl }
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aelastelement}{ m }
    {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_ae_lasttoken_tl { \tl_head:V { \tl_reverse:V #1 } }
        %% show results of these actions
        \textbf{ \l_ae_lasttoken_tl }
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Expecting to see & Getting \\
\textbf{T vs. T} & \aeupcasefirstelement{This is a test of my command} \\
\textbf{t vs. T} & \aeupcasefirstelement{this is a test of my command} \\
\textbf{d}       & \aelastelement{This is a test of my command}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to expand the contents of the brace groups, the `n` argument type doesn't do that.  If you change your `tl_set:Nn`'s to `\tl_set:Nx`'s, then it looks like your problem might be solved.

Comment: Whether or not that fixes your problem, as a side note, the `show` commands are really useful for diagnosing this sort of thing.  For example, after your first `\tl_set:Nn` command, add a `\tl_show:N \l_ae_lasttoken_tl` add have a look at your console.

Comment: That solves the problem with changing to upper case.  But my second command still doesn't behave properly.

Comment: thanks for the commend about `\tl_show:N`.  that is useful!

Comment: @ScottH. is right. I don't know about `xparse` but `\uppercase` works the same way, `\MakeUppercase` on the other hand is not expandable but the `t` will show up as `T`. Are you interested in `xstring` solutions? The `\StrRight` macro comes to mind. The first element can easily be extracted with plainTeX solutions.

Comment: They're super useful! (and there are a bunch of them: `\tl_show:N`, `\seq_show:N`, `\clist_show:N` etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This defines a conditional that tests if the last item in a token list is uppercase; the token list should consist only of ASCII characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \ae_if_last_uc:n #1 { T , F , TF }
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_ae_testa_tl { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_ae_testb_tl { \text_uppercase:V \l_ae_testa_tl }
  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_ae_testa_tl \l_ae_testb_tl
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \text_uppercase:n { V }

% A test
\ae_if_last_uc:nTF { abc } { \typeout{UC} } { \typeout{LC} }
\ae_if_last_uc:nTF { abC } { \typeout{UC} } { \typeout{LC} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\stop
```

The test outputs

> LC
>   UC

Your problem is common: `\tl_to_uppercase:n` (that is, the primitive `\uppercase`) is not expandable.

---

Let's look at your macros.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\aeupcasefirstelement}{ m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_ae_lasttoken_tl        { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_ae_upper_lasttoken_tl  { \tl_to_uppercase:n {  \l_ae_lasttoken_tl } }
  %% show results of these actions
  \textbf{ \l_ae_lasttoken_tl {~   vs.  ~} \l_ae_upper_lasttoken_tl }
 }
```

With `\aeupcasefirstelement{abc}` you store in `\l_ae_lasttoken_tl` the tokens `\tl_head:n{a}` and in `\l_ae_upper_lasttoken_tl` the tokens

```
\tl_to_uppercase:n{\l_ae_lasttoken_tl}
```

which is surely not what you want. The fact that the printed result seems to be correct is purely incidental, because during typesetting TeX expands and executes tokens. In order to store the first item in `\l_ae_lasttoken_tl` you need to *expand* the function `\tl_item:nn`, so use

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_ae_lasttoken_tl { \tl_item:nn { #1 } }
```

would be the correct idiom. For uppercasing, you have to resort to `\text_uppercase:n` as I did above, or do the uppercasing in a different and indirect fashion:

```
\exp_args:Nx \tl_to_uppercase:n
 {
  \exp_not:n { \tl_set:Nn \l_ae_lasttoken_uppercase_tl } { \l_ae_lasttoken_tl }
 }
```

(defining a variant `\tl_to_uppercase:x` would be better, of course).

The biggest problem is that `\tl_to_uppercase:n` is not expandable and does its work in a curious way. Also note that `\tl_to_uppercase:n` no longer exists in `expl3`, as its oddity and the way it works are not in par with the scope of `expl3` code.

Comment: Nice solution.  Can you explain why my approach of reversing the string and then trying to grab the head is failing to work?

Answer (score 6):

This grabs the last char and stuffs it in `\lastchar`.  Then it uppercases that char and stuffs it in `\uplastchar`.  Then, a simple `\if` will differentiate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\def\strng{This is a test of the emergency broadcast system}
\strng

\substring[q]{\strng}{$}{$}
\edef\lastchar{\thestring}

\caseupper[q]{\thestring}
\edef\uplastchar{\thestring}

\lastchar~\uplastchar

\if\lastchar\uplastchar SAME\else DIFFERENT\fi

\end{document}
```

p.s. In general, the strings cannot contain macros, though there are various exceptions and some workarounds, if necessary.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I was hoping to stick with something in `xpl3`.

Comment: @A.Ellett  Understood.

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility to explore is `pdfTeX` primitive `\pdfmatch`. 
Macro `\islastcap` checks if the state of the last letter in the string,
ignoring other characters.

```
\def\islastcap#1{%
\ifnum\pdfmatch subcount 1 {[A-Z][^a-zA-Z]*$}{#1}=1 %
[U] \else [L] \fi \ #1}

\def\str{ arl kdS   }  

\islastcap{\str}

\islastcap{\str a  }

\islastcap{\str .  }

\islastcap{\str . Y;  }

\islastcap{\str . Yn/T/f/;  }

\bye
```

The output:

```
[U] arl kdS
[L] arl kdS a
[U] arl kdS .
[U] arl kdS . Y;
[L] arl kdS . Yn/T/f/;
```